# Regular expression to validate employee id

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want a regular expression to validate employee ids which are
UC-00001,
UC-00012,
UC-000100. etc

"UC-000" is constant but after that if one digit number exist it becomes UC-00001 and if more den one digit exist then only three zeros needs to be constant.(UC-00010)

I tried using `preg_match(/[U]{1}[C]{1}-[0]{3}[0-9]$/)` but its not validating properly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need `{1}`, that's the default. And you don't need to put single characters inside `[]`. If you want to match `UC-`, just put `UC-` in the regexp.

Comment: And what if there is 100? or 1000?

Comment: It should be UC-000100 and UC-0001000 @The fourth bird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match three zeroes and then either from 00 to 09 or from 10 up..

```
^UC-000(?:0\d|[1-9]\d*)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `UC-000` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `0\d` Match 0 and a single digit 0-9 (Or use `[1-9]` to not match 00000)
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-9]\d*` Match a digit 1-9 and optional digits
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7VD0em/1)

```
$strings = [
    "UC-00001",
    "UC-00012",
    "UC-000100",
    "UC-00001",
    "UC-00010",
    "UC-00000",
    "UC-000010",
    "UC-0000100"
];
$pattern = "~^UC-000(?:0\d|[1-9]\d*)$~";
foreach ($strings as $s) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $s)) {
        echo "Match: $s" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "Not match: $s" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output

```
Match: UC-00001
Match: UC-00012
Match: UC-000100
Match: UC-00001
Match: UC-00010
Match: UC-00000
Not match: UC-000010
Not match: UC-0000100
```

Comment: Thank you so much @The fourth bird... It works

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is logically correct, save that you didn't allow for multiple digits after the leading `000`.  I would use this version:

```regex
^UC-[0-9]{5,}$
```

PHP script:

```php
$input = "UC-000100";
if (preg_match("/^UC-[0-9]{5,}$/", $input)) {
    echo "VALID";
}
```

Comment: But its also matching UC-000010 or UC-0000100. It should be only three zeros if there is two digit number @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Then I suggest making your life easy and just using `^UC-[0-9]{5,}$`.